# .(dot) vs [ ] property assignment result differs for copied object

Tags: javascript, properties

I have stumbled upon something that bugs me. I had to copy one object so I have written a helper function for that task.

```
function deepCopy2(target, obj) {

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (typeof obj[prop] !== 'object') {
                target.prop = obj[prop];
            } else {
                var embedded = {};
                deepCopy2(embedded, obj[prop]);
                target.prop = embedded;
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work. So I have just changed .(dot) assignment into [ ] as is shown below, and it works.

```
function deepCopy1(target, obj) {

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (typeof obj[prop] !== 'object') {
                target[prop] = obj[prop]; // changed here
            } else {
                var embedded = {};
                deepCopy1(embedded, obj[prop]);
                target[prop] = embedded; // changed here
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

If I do the following.

```
var obj = {
    name: 'john',
    getName: function() { return true; },
    inner: { age: 23 }
};

var newObj1 = deepCopy1({}, obj);
var newObj2 = deepCopy2({}, obj);

console.log(obj);
console.log(newObj1);
console.log(newObj2);
```

I get

```
{name: "john", getName: ƒ, inner: {…}}
{name: "john", getName: ƒ, inner: {…}}
{prop: {…}}
```

Meaning that the first function failed and instead of copying properties one by one, It just created property called `prop`.

I have found this [Valid property names, property assignment and access in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999914/valid-property-names-property-assignment-and-access-in-javascript) as well as this [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) and searched also on MDN but nothing leads to the answer.

I have also looked whether `prop` name can be freely used and didn't find any restrictions.

Can anyone explain to me why the first approach doesn't work while the second does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, there is two ways to retrieve an object property:

```
object[prop]

/* OR */

object.prop
```

You may ask, why?

Now there is a difference among the two.

**1 . `object.prop`**

In this approach, the `prop` is used as a property name.

Meaning, this way of retrieving says that you already know that the property `prop` exist in that `object`.

```
var object = {
        dummy: 1,
        prop: 2
    }

console.log(object.prop);  // Outputs 2
```

When the property is absent:

```
var object = {
        dummy: 1
    }

console.log(object.prop);  // Outputs undefined
```

Because there is no such property (that is why it is undefined).

**2. `object[prop]`**

In this approach, you are using the `prop` as an variable instead of a property name.

Meaning, the `prop` can be any value and this value can or cannot be a defined property in an object.

```
var prop = 'prop';
var object = {
        dummy: 1,
        prop: 2
    }

console.log(object[prop]);  // Outputs 2
```

Same when it is absent:

```
var prop = 'prop';
var object = {
        dummy: 1
    }

console.log(object[prop]);  // Outputs undefined
```

Because of the same reason.

However, if you add that property to that object later:

```
var prop = 'prop';
var object = {
        dummy: 1
    }

console.log(object[prop]);  // Outputs undefined

object.prop = 2;
console.log(object[prop]);  // Outputs 2

prop = 'abc';
console.log(object[prop]);  // Outputs undefined

object['abc'] = 3;
console.log(object[prop]);  // Outputs 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target.prop
// same as
target['prop']
```

does not use `prop`
 as variable, but works as hardcoded property with the name `prop`. The variable is not used here.

```
target[prop]
```

takes the variable `prop` and uses the value of it as key.

Comment: Not really sure how I overlooked that, thanks.